# how to show a map labels on top of Geotiff raster in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, raster, geotiff

i'm working on an web application that visualize solar data offor a GeoTIFF but when i add the tiff raster it covers the cities names, is it possible to add a top layer but shows only cities.

this how i want my map to look

[image]

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/